# Marcar a data atual no DataPicker

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-ui, datapicker

Colegas,

Como eu faço para que no dataPicker a data atual fique marcada e alterar as datas anteriores que estão desabilitadas? Veja:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Consegui desabilitar as datas anteriores usando o código abaixo, mas elas ficam pretas e acabam confundindo e a data atual não fica marcado.

```
<!-- datepicker -->
<script src="plugins/datepicker/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>

<script>
//Date picker
$('#datepicker').datepicker({
  autoclose: true,
  startDate: "date"
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consegui resolver. Coloquei o código abaixo:

```
todayHighlight: true
```

Para mais configurações acesse [esse site](https://uxsolutions.github.io/bootstrap-datepicker/?markup=input&format=&weekStart=&startDate=&endDate=&startView=0&minViewMode=0&maxViewMode=4&todayBtn=false&clearBtn=false&language=en&orientation=auto&multidate=&multidateSeparator=&keyboardNavigation=on&forceParse=on#sandbox). Tem como configurar seu datapicker.